# Calculate average asset price when using netting instead of hedging

Tags: python, pandas, math, trading

I'm trying to come up with a formula to calculate the average entry/position price to further update my stop loss and take profit.

For example opened BTC buy position with amount of 1 when price was 20000.
Later when price dropped down to 19000 we made another buy using the same amount of 1, "avereging" the position to the middle, so end up with position at 19500 with amount of 2.

Where I'm struggling is what if we want to increase the order size on each price.

Say 1 at 20000, 1.5 at 19500, 2 at 19000 and so on.

Or made new buys of the same amount but shorter distance between.

Inital buy at 20000. then 19000 then 19150

Or combine these two variants.

I use mainly Python and Pandas. Maybe the latter one has some built-in function which I'm not aware of. I checked the official Pandas docs, but found only regular mean function.

Comment: In trading `VWAP` Volume-Weighted Average Price is used. Google this. It is calculated as `sum(volume * price) / sum(volume). For your first example `VWAP = 19388.88...` IMVHO increasing size while "averaging down" is a very bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, improved, and posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Yuri's suggestion to look into VWAP, I came up with the following code, which is more advanced and allows you to use different contract/volume sizes and increase/decrease "distance" between orders.

As an example here I used avarage price of BTC 20000 and increased steps distance using 1.1 multiplier as well as increased volume. Operated in Binance futures terms, where you can buy minimum 1 contract for 10$.

The idea is to find sweet spot for orders distance, volume, stop loss and take profit while avereging down.

```
# initial entry price
initial_price = 20000

# bottom price
bottom_price = 0

# enter on every 5% price drop
step = int(initial_price*0.05)

# 1.1 to increase distance between orders, 0.9 to decrease
step_multiplier = 1.1

# initial volume size in contracts
initial_volume = 1

# volume_multiplier, can't be less than 1, in case of use float, will be rounded to decimal number
volume_multiplier = 1.1

# defining empty arrays
prices = []
volumes = []

# checking if we are going to use simple approach with 1 contract volume and no sep or volume multiplier
if step_multiplier == 1 and volume_multiplier == 1:
   prices = range(initial_price,bottom_price,-step)   
else:
   # defining current price and volume vars
   curr_price = initial_price
   curr_volume = initial_volume   
   # Checking if current price is still bigger then defined bottom price
   while curr_price > bottom_price:
      # adding current price to the list
      prices.append(curr_price)
      # calulating next order price
      curr_price = curr_price-step*step_multiplier
      # checking if volume multiplier is bigger then 1
      if volume_multiplier > 1:
         # adding current volume to the list
         volumes.append(int(curr_volume))
         # calulating next order volume         
         curr_volume = curr_volume*volume_multiplier

print("Prices:")
for price in prices:
      print(price)

print("Volumes:")
for volume in volumes:
      print(volume)      

print("Prices array length", len(prices))
print("Volumes array length", len(volumes))

a = [item1 * item2 for item1, item2 in zip(prices, volumes)]
b = volumes

print("Average position price when price will reach",prices[-1], "is", sum(a)/sum(b))
```